# Using filterNot with a Map

Tags: scala

I have a simple map

```
val m = Map("a1" -> "1", "b2" -> "2", "c3" -> "3")
val someList = List("b", "d")
m.filterNot( (k,v) => someList.exist(l => k.startsWith(l)) )
```

I'm getting an error:

```
error: missing parameter type
```

I'm doing something silly here I'm sure, why isn' this compiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filterNot` needs a `case` keyword and `{}` when you extract `k, v` from tuple.

*note that its not `exist` its `exists`*

```
m.filterNot { case (k,v) => someList.exists(l => k.startsWith(l)) }
```

or

```
m.filterNot(pair => someList.exists(l => pair._1.startsWith(l)))
```

*Explanation*

As you are extracting k, v from the tuple using extractor syntax you have to use `case` keyword and `{}`

Without extractor syntax you can do

```
m.filterNot(pair => someList.exists(l => pair._1.startsWith(l)))
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val m = Map("a1" -> "1", "b2" -> "2", "c3" -> "3")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a1 -> 1, b2 -> 2, c3 -> 3)

scala> val someList = List("b", "d")
someList: List[String] = List(b, d)

scala>  m.filterNot { case (k,v) => someList.exists(l => k.startsWith(l)) }
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a1 -> 1, c3 -> 3)
```

**Without extractor syntax**

Now you need not use `case` keyword and `{}` as we are not using extracting the key and value using extractor syntax

```
scala> m.filterNot(pair => someList.exists(l => pair._1.startsWith(l)))
res18: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a1 -> 1, c3 -> 3)

scala> val m = Map("a1" -> "1", "b2" -> "2", "c3" -> "3")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a1 -> 1, b2 -> 2, c3 -> 3)

scala> val someList = List("b", "d")
someList: List[String] = List(b, d)

scala> m.filterNot(pair => someList.exists(l => pair._1.startsWith(l)))
res19: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a1 -> 1, c3 -> 3)
```

Comment: Or simply: `(pair => someList.exists(pair._1.startsWith))`

Comment: Hmm, I don't see it.  All of your examples pass the `l` parameter explicitly: `startsWith(l)` Actually it can be reduced even more, `m.filterNot(someList exists _._1.startsWith)`, but now we're in danger of obscuring the code by being too cute with the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is this: the `filterNot` method accepts one parameter, while you are defining a list of two parameters. This confuses the compiler and that message is the result.

In order to solve it, you can use the following syntax (notice the usage of pattern matching with the `case` keyword):

```
m.filterNot { case (k,v) => someList.exist(l => k.startsWith(l)) }
```

Using the pattern matching like this creates a `PartialFunction` that will be decompose key and value and be applied like a normal function to your `Map`.

Comment: Note that since you are not using the value you can discard the value using a `_` like this: `m.filterNot { case (k, _) => someList.exist(l => k.startsWith(l)) }`

Comment: At some point in the future this annoyance will be removed according to the language creator, Martin Odersky: https://youtu.be/_2oGY8l67jk?t=34m50s

Answer (score 1):

Using for comprehension syntax, extraction and filtering may be achieved as follows,

```
for ( pair@(k,v) <- m; l <- someList if !k.startsWith(l)) yield pair
```